# How do I post data in http header from MVC to webapi post method

Tags: c#, post, asp.net-web-api, model-view-controller

I am creating prototype of application where in I am trying to send data in request header and body from C# MVC Controller and also created web api project Post action to process the request.

My code goes like this::

MVC Project code to Post Request:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
   {
       public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
       {
           VM VM = new VM();
           VM.Name = " TEST Name";
           VM.Address =  " TEST Address ";

           using (var client = new HttpClient())
           {
               client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:58297");
               client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
               client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

               client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("username","test");

               var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(VM);
               var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
               var result1 = await client.PostAsync("api/Values/Post", content);
           }

           return View();
       }
   }
```

My code in WEB API project :

```
    // POST api/values
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]API.VM vm)
{
    try
    {
        HttpRequestMessage re = new HttpRequestMessage();

        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"E:\Apple\txt.log", false);

        var headers = re.Headers;
        string token = "";

        if (headers.Contains("username"))
        {
            token = headers.GetValues("username").First();
        }

        sw.WriteLine("From header" + token);

        sw.WriteLine("From BODY" + vm.Name);
        sw.WriteLine("From BODY" + vm.Address);
        sw.WriteLine("Line2");
        sw.Close();
        return Ok("Success");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return InternalServerError(ex);
    }
}
```

What I have understood is [FromBody]API.VM vm gets data from Http request body which means vm object is getting data from HTTP Request body.I am able to get request body. I am not able to understand how do I pass data in header from MVC controller (I want to pass JSON Data) and retrieve data in WEB Api post method?

I have used client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("username","test"); in MVC project to pass header data and

```
HttpRequestMessage re = new HttpRequestMessage();
              var headers = re.Headers;
              string token = "";

              if (headers.Contains("username"))
              {
                  token = headers.GetValues("username").First();
              }
```

in WEB API project to get data but I am not able to get username value.

Comment: You would need to enable `CORS` in order to get your headers. Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors and then in your `Register` method under `WebApiConfig.cs`, add this line: `EnableCors();`. Once done, you can access your header variable as: `IEnumerable<string> values = new List<string>();
actionContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValues("username", out values);`

Comment: Did you get this to work at your end?

Comment: yes, this solution worked. I was looking for ways to mark it as solution..

Comment: I have posted this an answer so you can do the needful at your end. Thanks

Comment: thank you for solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get your data via `headers`, you would need to enable CORS: `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors` in your project and then in your `Register` method under `WebApiConfig.cs`, add this line: `EnableCors();`.

Once done, you can access your header variable as:

```
IEnumerable<string> values = new List<string>(); 
actionContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValues("username", out values);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get all headers being passed to a method of a web API using below lines inside that web API method:

```
HttpActionContext actionContext = this.ActionContext;
var headers = actionContext.Request.Headers;
```